# Scala for-comprehension yielding result from multiple variable bindings

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I am very curious how Scala desugars the following for-comprehension:

```
for {
  a <- Option(5)
  b = a * 2
  c <- if (b == 10) Option(100) else None
} yield b + c
```

My difficulty comes from having both `b` and `c` in the yield, because they seem to be bound at different steps

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about your main doubt: `yield`ing bindings from different steps of a `for`-comprehension is not an issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sure is not an issue, i just wanted to know the equivalent flatMap/Map desugar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even ask the compiler. The following command:

```
scala -Xprint:parser -e "for {
  a <- Option(5)
  b = a * 2
  c <- if (b == 10) Option(100) else None
} yield b + c"
```

yields this output

```
[[syntax trees at end of                    parser]] // scalacmd7617799112170074915.scala
package <empty> {
  object Main extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def main(args: Array[String]): scala.Unit = {
      final class $anon extends scala.AnyRef {
        def <init>() = {
          super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        Option(5).map(((a) => {
  val b = a.$times(2);
  scala.Tuple2(a, b)
})).flatMap(((x$1) => x$1: @scala.unchecked match {
          case scala.Tuple2((a @ _), (b @ _)) => if (b.$eq$eq(10))
  Option(100)
else
  None.map(((c) => b.$plus(c)))
        }))
      };
      new $anon()
    }
  }
}
```

Taking only the piece you are interested in and improving the readability, you get this:

```
Option(5).map(a => {
  val b = a * 2
  (a, b)
}).flatMap(_ match {
  case (_, b) => 
    if (b == 10)
      Option(100)
    else
      None.map(c => b + c)
})
```

#### Edit

As reported in a comment, literally translating from the compiler output seems to highlight a bug in how the desugared expression is rendered. The sum should be `map`ped on the result of the `if` expression, rather then on the `None` in the `else` branch:

```
Option(5).map(a => {
  val b = a * 2
  (a, b)
}).flatMap(_ match {
  case (_, b) => 
    (if (b == 10) Option(100) else None).map(c => b + c)
})
```

It's probably worth it to ask the compiler team if this is a bug.

Comment: Hm. It's should not be `None.map` (as that is noop), but rather `(if ... else ...).map`

Comment: I was surprised as well, but I just improved on the compiler output readability (cmp. `None.map(((c) => b.$plus(c)))`). I'll double check, as I mentioned I was surprised as well.

Comment: This seems to be a bug on how it *prints* the if-else, always doing a line break and never wrapping expression in parentheses.

Comment: You're probably right, I edited the answer to reflect your observation. I'll open an issue on the `scalac` tracker to get a better understanding of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is the sanitized output of `desugar` - a command available in [Ammonite REPL](http://ammonite.io/#Ammonite-REPL):

```
Option(5)
  .map { a =>
    val b = a * 2;
    (a, b)
  }
  .flatMap { case (a, b) =>
      (if (b == 10) Option(100) else None)
        .map(c => b + c)
  }
```

Both `b` and `c` can be present in `yield` because it does not desugar to *chained* calls to map/flatMap, but rather to *nested* calls.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know Ammonite could do this. My answer just used the compiler support, but this is very good to know.

Comment: @stefanobaghino the code from Ammonite is still filled with intermediate variables, expanded `apply`s and type parameters. I removed all these to focus on substance just like you did.

Comment: Well, the compiler output has it as well. I'm fairly sure that all the Ammonite does is just asking the compiler, hence all the noise. :)

Answer (score 1):

These two codes are equivalent:

```
scala> for {
     |   a <- Option(5)
     |   b = a * 2
     |   c <- if (b == 10) Option(100) else None
     | } yield b + c
res70: Option[Int] = Some(110)

scala> for {
     |   a <- Option(5)
     |   b = a * 2
     |   if (b == 10) 
     |   c <- Option(100) 
     | } yield b + c
res71: Option[Int] = Some(110)
```

Since there is no collection involved, yielding multiple values, there is only one big step - or, arguable, 3 to 4 small steps. If a would have been None, the whole loop would have been terminated early, yielding a None.

The desugaring is a flatMap/withFilter/map.

Comment: No, they're not. `if (b == 10)` in latter case is `withFilter`.